# ASP.NET outputting <br> tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm working on a website built in .net and its outputting linbreaks after each span for some reason. The code thats outputting the line breaks is

```
<asp:DataList ID="DL_Items" runat="server" DataKeyField="ProductID" oneditcommand="DL_Items_EditCommand" 
        oncancelcommand="DL_Items_CancelCommand" 
        onupdatecommand="DL_Items_UpdateCommand" 
        onitemcommand="DL_Items_ItemCommand" 
        onitemdatabound="DL_Items_ItemDataBound" 
    ondeletecommand="DL_Items_DeleteCommand" RepeatLayout="Flow">
<ItemTemplate>
```

I've tried looking around google for better solutions to this and all I could find was a way to generate the code in a table which i do not want. Is there a reason why the above code is generating line breaks, `<br>`

---

Compete itemtemplate

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="EC_Item_Left_Panel">
    <ul class="EC_Item_Left_UL">
    <li>
        <asp:Image ID="IM_PIC" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("path") %>' /></li>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="BT_Edit" CssClass="ecom_edit_tbn" CommandName="Edit" runat="server">Edit Item</asp:LinkButton></li>
               <li class="deleteRow">

 <asp:LinkButton ID="BT_Delete" ToolTip='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' runat="server" CssClass="deleteButton ecom_remove_tbn" Text="Delete" ForeColor="Red"></asp:LinkButton> 
        <asp:Button ID="deleteCommand" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="deleteCommand" style="display:none" /> 
</li>

            <%--<asp:LinkButton CssClass="ecom_remove_tbn" ID="BT_Remove" CommandName="Delete" runat="server">Remove</asp:LinkButton>--%>
            <li><asp:LinkButton CssClass="ecom_link_tbn" ID="BT_Link" runat="server" CommandName="linkproduct">Linked Items</asp:LinkButton></li>
    </ul>    
    </div>
    <div>

     <div class="Item_Right_Panel">
    <ul class="EC_Item_Top_UL">
         <li><label>ProductID </label><span><%#Eval("ProductID")%></span></li>
     <li><label>Enabled </label><span><%#Eval("Enabled")%></span></li>
     <li><label>Title </label><asp:Label ID="LB_ProductTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>'></asp:Label></li>
     <li><label>Product Code </label><span><%#Eval("ProductCode")%></span></li>
     <li><label>Category </label><span><%#Eval("Category")%></span></li>

     <%--Callum--%>
     <li><label>Price</label><span><%#Eval("Sale_Price")%></span></li>
     <li><label>Subcategory</label><span><%#Eval("Subcat")%></span></li>
     <li><label>Designer</label><span><%#Eval("DesignerName")%></span></li>
     <li><label>Range</label><span><%#Eval("Range")%></span></li>
     <li><label>Height</label></li>
     <li><label>Length</label></li>
     <li><label>Width</label></li>

     <li><label>Description </label><span><%#Eval("Description")%></span></li>
    </ul>

       <ul class="EC_Item_Bottom_UL">
    <li><label>KeyFieldName </label><span><%#Eval("KeyFieldName")%></span></li>
     <li><label>ItemField1Name </label><span><%#Eval("ItemField1Name")%></span></li>
     <li><label>ItemField2Name </label><span><%#Eval("ItemField2Name")%></span></li>
          <li><label>ItemField3Name </label><span><%#Eval("ItemField3Name")%></span></li>
          <li><label>ItemField3Name </label><span><%#Eval("ItemField3Name")%></span></li>
          <li><label>Include File </label><span>   <%# IncludeTitle(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "include"))%>  </span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </div>       
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: @oded I've added the additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataList creates the br's(See documentation of Flow layout at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).
If you don't want br's or any extra markup between elements, I'd suggest you to use a Repeater instead.